# VBA Clear formatting hides line breaks until formula bar is activated? Why?

Tags: excel, vba, format

I have noticed that when clearing formatting, `.ClearFormats`, of a sheet in Excel via VBA it also appears it clears the line feeds in text strings inside cells. However, when you click and activate the formula bar and exits it again, the line feeds reappears.

What is going on? And is there a way to show the line feeds in the cells again with VBA? I am currently clearing formatting for faster savings (cell colorings are slowing down my saving time), and I would like to avoid having to manually click every header and the formula bar everytime.

This is my procedure at the moment. (I had to add one image instead of four since I do not have enough reputation points for more than two links.)

1. After my code is run and formatting is done.
2. Then I run the line `ActiveWorksheet.Cells.ClearFormats`
3. If I run my formatting procedure again (unchanged text strings in cells)
4. I then click on cell D1 --> Click in formula bar --> Click in random other cell

[Print Screens of the different stages of the explained procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJcx9.png)

Why is this happening? And is there a way to avoid it without resetting default formatting for each "format setting" (e.g. background color, border, font etc.)?

Comment: Wrap text in a cell is [Cell alignment Format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Align-text-in-a-cell-b2489a1f-6c89-45b7-9562-bbc287aa71ea). So "Clear Formats" will clearing this too.

Comment: Thanks for the info Axel.
Fratyx's answer worked like a charm.

Comment: That's fine. If it was helpful you should accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `ActiveWorksheet.Cells.WrapText = True` after your `ActiveWorksheet.Cells.ClearFormats`

Or specialize it to a range of cells if not all cells should be wrapped.